# How do I determine a YouTube video's API id from its URL

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to use the youtube api to determine the status of a video for a given url, e.g.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S_PU9-9Cr0

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=-S_PU9-9Cr0&part=status&key={API_KEY}

However, this returns an empty list; it appears that the `v` parameter is *not* the YouTube API's video id. How can I obtain the latter from the former?

Comment: I see the `v` parameter value matches the Video ID shown in stats for nerds. I tried to play the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-S_PU9-9Cr0 but it is no longer available because the YouTube account associated with this video has been terminated.

Comment: What's "stats for nerds"? I know the video is unavailable - that's precisely what I'm trying to determine. I'm writing a cms function to check for broken links.

Comment: If the video is available, you can right click on the video, and select "stats for nerds" to view some details about the video such as Video ID, resolution, bandwidth. Maybe you can try an API call to an available video first.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Yeah, I see the video id there matches the `v` parameter. So I tried an available video, and it does appear that 'v' and 'video id' refer to the same thing; I get some real results for a video that hasn't been taken down. It appears as if there's no way of differentiating between a video that has been taken down and one that never existed but, for my purposes, I might be able to get away with not worrying about it! Thanks.